# openmp loop result goes to zero

Tags: c++, openmp

Im trying to implent my code with openmp but i am having some trouble. My code has several loops so i tried to parallelize each "for" blocks in order to make my code run faster. However im having problems parallelize certain for blocks. The issue is basically that the results I get when I parallelize tend to 0, while when the code runs without openmp they dont.

This is an example of a block im trying to parallelize (there are 3 of them):

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(j)
     for(i=1;i<127;i++)
        for(j=1;j<127;j++)
           {
              dpx=dp(p[i+1][j],p[i-1][j]);
              dpy=dp(p[i][j+1],p[i][j-1]);
              d2px=d2p(p[i+1][j],p[i][j],p[i-1][j]);
              dpx=dp(p[i][j+1],p[i][j],p[i][j-1]);

              f=F(d2px,d2py,dpx,dpy,p[i][j],i,j);
              p1[i][j]=p[i][j] + f;
            }
```

Does anyone has an idea why im getting results that tend to 0 for the p or the p1 value? I thought that perhaps the dpx,dpy... needed to be private as well but that didnt worked either.

Comment: There are cross dependencies between iterations of the loop, given that any given iteration may update before another the behavior of this code when parallelized is undefined.

Comment: It was indeed because od the cross dependencies between the iterations of the loop. I gathered all calculations in just one and that solved the problem. Thank you for you feedback

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `dpx` twice without using it. Is that intended? Or did you want the second call to be `d2py`? You never set `d2py`, and then use it, which seems suspicious.

Comment: Yes i did made a mistake typing, it is suposed to be d2py where the second dpx is